# RDFS analogue to owl:equivalentClass?

Tags: sparql, owl, rdfs, graphdb, rdfs+

I have triples that say patient `P` participates in health care encounter `E` which has output `M`, a drug prescription.  Prescriptions can `mention` a drug from the Drug Ontology, or DrOn.

In this case, let's say that `M1` mentions the cholesterol-lowering medication atorvastatin, which was imported into DrOn from ChEBI as http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_39548:

`prefix obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
:M1 obo:IAO_0000142 obo:CHEBI_39548 .`

ChEBI has an axiom that obo:CHEBI_39548 has the role http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_35821, "anticholesteremic drug".  That makes it easy to find patients who have been prescribed atorvastatin, or other drugs with the same role.

Unfortunately, DrOn created its own terms for some drugs instead of importing them from ChEBI.  For example, another cholesterol-lowering drug, rosuvastatin, is modeled as http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00018679 instead of http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CHEBI_38545.  ChEBI's term for rosuvastatin is also annotated with the role obo:CHEBI_39548, but obo:DRON_00018679 is not.  So patients in my dataset who were prescribed rosuvastatin do not show up in my existing role-based query.

I have these data in a GraphDB RDFS-plus repository, and I'd prefer not to change the reasoning level right now.  If it was an OWL repository, I would just say

`obo:CHEBI_38545 owl:equivalentClass obo:DRON_00018679`

**Is there something similar I can do with RDFS, or a GraphDB custom ruleset?**

Comment: Do you need just `obo:CHEBI_38545 rdfs:subClassOf obo:DRON_00018679 . obo:DRON_00018679 rdfs:subClassOf  obo:CHEBI_38545`? Also, isn't `owl:equivalentClass` within RDFS+?

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks, I guess reciprocal `rdfs:subClassOf` would work, even if it does look a little funny.  Sorry, I didn't try asserting `owl:equivalentClass` yet.  I'll do that now with a small dataset for thoroughness.

Comment: Given that `owl:equivalentClass` is just syntactic sugar, the one and only answer is as Stanislav said, `rdfs:subClassOf` in both directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If it was an OWL repository, I would just say
>
> `obo:CHEBI_38545 owl:equivalentClass obo:DRON_00018679`
>
> *Is there something similar I can do with RDFS, or a GraphDB custom ruleset?*

**First**

You obviously can replace `owl:equivalentClass` with two reciprocal `rdfs:subClassOf`. As for the very equivalence of these formulations, I suppose this is relevant:

- OWL 2 Direct Semantics, [Table 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/#Class_Expression_Axioms);
- OWL 2 RDF-Based Semantics, [Table 5.8](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-rdf-based-semantics/#table-semcond-rdfs) and [Table 5.9](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-rdf-based-semantics/#table-semcond-eqdis).

**Second**

`owl:equivalentClass` is already within RDFS-Plus.

From chapter 7 of the 1st edition of *Semantic Web for the Working Ontologist*, where RDFS-Plus was first introduced:

> RDFS-Plus provides a more intuitive expression of class equivalence, using the construct `owl:equivalentClass`.

In GraphDB, the *RDFS-Plus* and *RDFS-Plus (Optimized)* rulesets support `owl:equivalentClass`. There are the following rule in the `builtin_rdfsPlus-optimized.pie` file:

```
Id: owl_EquivClassBySubClass

  a <rdfs:subClassOf> b [Constraint b != a]
  b <rdfs:subClassOf> a [Cut]
------------------------------------
  a <owl:equivalentClass> b
```

and the following axioms:

```
<owl:equivalentClass> <rdf:type> <owl:TransitiveProperty>
<owl:equivalentClass> <rdf:type> <owl:SymmetricProperty>
<owl:equivalentClass> <rdfs:subPropertyOf> <rdfs:subClassOf>
```

In higher profiles, two rules are used instead:

```
Id: scm_eqc1
  c1 <owl:equivalentClass> c2            [Constraint c1 != c2 ]
  -------------------------------
  c1 <rdfs:subClassOf> c2
  c2 <rdfs:subClassOf> c1

Id: scm_eqc2
  c1 <rdfs:subClassOf> c2                [Constraint c1 != c2 ]
  c2 <rdfs:subClassOf> c1                
  -------------------------------
  c1 <owl:equivalentClass> c2
```

Answer (score 1):

When I use @StanislavKralin's reciprocal `rdfs:subClassOf` appraoch in an RDFS+ GraphDB repo...

- inserting some triples about classes `:x` and `:y`, with instance `:z` of class `:x`
- asserting that `:x` and `:y` are subclasses of one another

`PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix : <http://localhost/>
insert data {
    :x a owl:Class .
    :y a owl:Class .
    :z a :x .
    :x rdfs:subClassOf :y .
    :y rdfs:subClassOf :x .
}`

Then query for all triples about `:x`,`:y`, and `:z`

`select * where { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
    filter(regex(str(?s), "localhost"))
}
order by ?s ?p ?o`

I get the `owl:equivalentClass` for free!

`+----+---------------------+-----------+
| s  |          p          |     o     |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| :x | rdf:type            | owl:Class |
| :x | rdfs:subClassOf     | :x        |
| :x | rdfs:subClassOf     | :y        |
| :x | owl:equivalentClass | :x        |
| :x | owl:equivalentClass | :y        |
| :y | rdf:type            | owl:Class |
| :y | rdfs:subClassOf     | :x        |
| :y | rdfs:subClassOf     | :y        |
| :y | owl:equivalentClass | :x        |
| :y | owl:equivalentClass | :y        |
| :z | rdf:type            | :x        |
| :z | rdf:type            | :y        |
+----+---------------------+-----------+`